# Insert parent and (n) children using stored procedure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbctemplate

I am having some difficulty writing the stored procedure to insert a parent record and 'n' number of children records. I am using MySQL with Java and Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. My DB tables are:

```
contact:
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    ....

contact_phone:
    id
    contactId
    number
    ....
```

You can see the relationship is one-to-many. I am trying to write a stored procedure where I can pass in the contact information and an ArrayList of phone objects. There is some metadata associated with the phone number that I need to store. I want to do it in a stored procedure so I can rollback the transaction if one of the inserts fails for some reason.

Here is a simplified sample of what I am trying to do:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO contact(`lastName`,`firstName`,`primaryEmail`,`organizationId`) VALUE ('New Last','New First','New email',3);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @newContactId;
INSERT INTO contact_phone(`contactId`,`number`,`organizationId`) VALUE (@newContactId,'+18011234567',3);
INSERT INTO contact_phone(`contactId`,`number`,`organizationId`) VALUE (@newContactId,'+18017654321',3);
INSERT INTO contact_phone(`contactId`,`number`,`organizationId`) VALUE (@newContactId,'+18019876543',3);
COMMIT;
```

This is the beginning of my stored procedure. I am just not sure how to pass in an array of phone objects, loop through them, and insert new records.

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_contact`(
    IN lastName VARCHAR(128),
    IN firstName VARCHAR(128),
    IN primaryEmail VARCHAR(320),
    IN image_pointer VARCHAR(256),
    IN locationId BIGINT(20),
    IN organizationId BIGINT(20),
    IN facebookPSID VARCHAR(256),
    IN note TEXT,
    IN locationNote VARCHAR(128),
    IN inactiveDate BIGINT(20),
    IN ??? How do I pass in an ArrayList of objects for my phones?)
BEGIN
    DECLARE `_rollback` BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET `_rollback` = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO 
        contact(`lastName`, `firstName`, `primaryEmail`, `image_pointer`, `locationId`, `organizationId`, `facebookPSID`, `note`, `locationNote`, `inactiveDate`) 
    VALUES
        (lastName, firstName, primaryEmail, image_pointer, locationId, organizationId, FacebookPSID, note,  locationNote, inactiveDate);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @newContactId;
--  *** Here is where I am stuck
--  Need to loop through list of these and insert them
--  INSERT INTO contact_phone(`contactId`, `number`, `city`, `state`, `country`, `zip`, `type`, `primary`, `smsCapable`, `organizationId`) VALUES (@newContactId, number, city, state, country, zip, type, primary, smsCapable, organizationId);
    IF `_rollback` THEN
        SET @RESULT=1;
        ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
        SET @RESULT=0;
        COMMIT;
    END IF;
    SELECT @RESULT;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I would move this operation to JAVA where you can open a connection with transaction and do whatever inserts you want to do with looping. However if you'd like to use SP, you may have a chance with JSON, or delimited strings.

Comment: I am actually creating the inserts dynamically in a loop in Java right now just like in the first sample right now.